# How would I add a newline in a UL from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to add elements taken from an input box, put that into an array, and then display that in an unordered list. My problem is adding a `<br>` after each entry from Javascript after the value has been passed to the list.

Here is the code used to push to the list currently.

```
function addToList(){
  var incompleteList = document.getElementById("incompleteTaskList");
  incompleteList.append(currentTask);
 
}
```

Not sure how I would add a break after each new entry

Comment: Why do you need to add a BR in a UL? Sounds like you have a bug if you need to do that.

Comment: @epascarello when I add a value in from the input box, the first value will appear in the list but the next value doesn't line break so it just adds onto the original entry

Comment: So sounds like you are not adding to the UL correctly What is currentTask? I am guessing it is not an li. Show you code.

Comment: @epascarello ahh so currentTask is just a string value from the input box. I will try and make it an li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating new `<LI>` elements and setting their text content to the task name.

```js
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btn-add')

const addTask = e => {
  let txtTask = document.querySelector('.txt-task'),
      task = txtTask.value.trim()

  if (task) {
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.textContent = task
    document.querySelector('.tasks').append(li)
    txtTask.value = ''
  }
}

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', addTask)
```

```css
h1        { font-size: 1.25rem; }
h2, label { font-size: 1.00rem; }
```

```html
<h1>Task Manager</h1>
<div>
  <label>New Task</label>
  <input class="txt-task" type="text" />
  <button class="btn-add">Add</button>
</div>
<h2>Tasks</h2>
<ul class="tasks"></ul>
```

### Rendering application

Here is an example using a list data structure and rendering engine. It features auto-sorting and duplicate entry detection.

```js
const main = () => {
  new TaskManager('.task-app', {
    formConfig: {
      fieldLabel: 'New Task',
      buttonText: 'Add'
    },
    listConfig: {
      autoSort: true
    }
  })
}

class TaskForm {
  constructor(options) {
    let opts = Object.assign({}, TaskForm.defaultOptions, options)
    
    this.fieldLabel = opts.fieldLabel
    this.buttonText = opts.buttonText
  }

  addEvents(target) {
    target.querySelector('.btn-add').addEventListener('click', e => {
      let txtTask = document.querySelector('.txt-task'),
          task = txtTask.value.trim()
          
      if (task) {
        const addEvent = new CustomEvent('task-add', {
          detail: txtTask.value
        })
        target.dispatchEvent(addEvent);
        txtTask.value = ''
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <div>
        <label>${this.fieldLabel}</label>
        <input class="txt-task" type="text" />
        <button class="btn-add">${this.buttonText}</button>
      </div>
    `
  }
}

TaskForm.defaultOptions = {
  fieldLabel: 'New Task',
  buttonText: 'Add'
}

class TaskList {
  constructor(options) {
    this.tasks = []

    let opts = Object.assign({}, TaskList.defaultOptions, options)
    this.autoSort = opts.autoSort
  }
  
  addTask(task) {
    if (!this.tasks.includes(task)) {
      this.tasks.push(task)
      if (this.autoSort) this.tasks.sort()
    } else {
      console.log(`Task "${task}" already exists.`)
    }
  } 
  
  addEvents(target) {
    target.addEventListener('task-add', e => {
      this.addTask(e.detail)
      const addEvent = new CustomEvent('task-added')
      target.dispatchEvent(addEvent);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return `
      <ul>
        ${this.tasks.map(task => `<li>${task}</li>`).join('')}
      </ul>
    `
  }
}

TaskList.defaultOptions = {
  autoSort: false
}

class Mountable {
  constructor(target, options) {
    this.target = typeof target === 'string' ?
      document.querySelector(target) : target
    this.initialize(options)
    this.update()
  }
  
  update() {
    this.target.innerHTML = this.render()
    this.afterRender()
  }
}


class TaskManager extends Mountable {
  constructor(target, options) {
    super(target, options)
  }
  
  initialize(options) {
    this.form = new TaskForm(options.formConfig)
    this.taskList = new TaskList(options.listConfig)
  }
  
  afterRender() {
    this.target.addEventListener('task-added', e => {
      this.update()
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    })
    
    this.form.addEvents(this.target)
    this.taskList.addEvents(this.target)
  }
  
  render() {
    return `
      <h1>Task Manager</h1>
      ${this.form.render()}
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
      ${this.taskList.render()}
    `
  }
}

main()
```

```css
h1        { font-size: 1.25rem; }
h2, label { font-size: 1.00rem; }
```

```html
<div class="task-app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding a `<br>` using javascript. That's not the correct implementation approach.

Instead, you need to style this using CSS. Try adding below style rule:

> #incompleteTaskList li{display:block;}